# NSTableView autosave column widths does not restore columns when autosavename is changed

Tags: macos, nstableview

According to the Apple Docs when you change the autosave name of a NSTableView it will read the column widths from UserDefaults for that autosavename and adjust columns accordingly.

I can't seem to get this to work in the following scenario:

The user can choose one of two options to display Changes or Sessions in the tableView.  Changes has different columns to Sessions.

So to achieve this without using two separate NSTableViews I thought when the user changes the selection I could simply remove the existing columns and replace them with the required ones and then set the autosavename to either "ChangesTableView" or "SessionsTableView".  And then according to the Apple docs the tableView will read in the saved settings and adjust the columns.

This seems to half work.

If I close the app after setting the autosavename = "Name1" and the restart the app with the autosavename = "Name2" then the table will have no saved column data.

If I then change the autosavename to "Name1" the previously saved positions will be restored.

However if I now change the name to "Name2" and change the column positions and restart the app with the autosavename = "Name2" then the new positions are restored.

However if I now change the autosavename = "Name1" again then the previously save positions from "Name1" earlier are not longer there and the columns revert to defaults.

It seems that when you change the autosavename the settings under the old name are deleted.  So it seems you can't save positions under two different autosave names.

The docs say that if you set the autosavename to NIL then any previously saved data will be cleared.  There is no mention of also clearing data from any previously used autosavename if you change the autosavename.

Anyone have a specific solution for this, short of overlaying two NSTableViews with a tabbed view or something.

Comment: Using one table view for two tables isn't supported. Easy solution: Two table views and hide one. DIY solution: Save and restore the column widths yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I took Willeke's advice and save and restore myself.

Any time the columns are resized save to the autosave name

```
func tableViewColumnDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let changedTableView = notification.object as? NSTableView, changedTableView == self.detailsTableView else {
        return
    }
    
    // Now save the table positions ourself !
    let columnWidths = changedTableView.tableColumns.reduce([String : CGFloat](), { dict, col in
        var dict = dict
        dict[col.identifier.rawValue] = col.width
        return dict
    } )
    
    if let tableViewName = changedTableView.autosaveName {
        Foundation.UserDefaults.standard.set(columnWidths, forKey: tableViewName)
    }
}
```

And when the user selects to view another option recreate the table columns and set based on saved values

```
func columnWidths(tableViewName: String) -> [String: CGFloat] {
    if let widths = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: tableViewName) as? [String: CGFloat] {
        return widths
    } else {
        return [:]
    }
}

func loadDetailTableData(index: Int){
    guard let detailTableView = self.detailsTableView else {
        return
    }
    
    // Clear the tableView
    for tableColumn in detailTableView.tableColumns {
        detailTableView.removeTableColumn(tableColumn)
    }
    
    switch index {
    case 0:
        self.detailTableViewSetup(detailTableView, autosaveName: self.userChangesAutosaveName, headers: self.changeColumnHeaders)
    case 1:
        self.detailTableViewSetup(detailTableView, autosaveName: self.loginSessionAutosaveName, headers: self.sessionColumnHeaders)
    default:
        break
    }

    detailTableView.reloadData()
    
}
func detailTableViewSetup(_ tableView: NSTableView, autosaveName: String, headers: [String]){
    
    tableView.autosaveName = nil
    
    let widths = self.columnWidths(tableViewName: autosaveName)
    
    var columnNo: Int = 0
    for column in headers {
        let id = columnNo.toString
        let tableColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: id))
        tableColumn.title = column
        if let w = widths[id] {
            tableColumn.width = w
        }
        tableView.addTableColumn(tableColumn)
        columnNo += 1
    }
    tableView.autosaveName = autosaveName
    
}
```